# Post deployment bash script in Bicep file does not execute

Tags: bash, azure, powershell, azure-bicep

I want to deploy an Ubuntu VM on Azure and **automatically** execute a few lines of Bash code right after the VM is deployed. The Bash code is supposed to install PowerShell on the VM. To do this, I use this [Bicep file](https://github.com/fabioklr/pwsh_project/blob/main/main.bicep). Below you can see an extract of that Bicep file where I specify what Bash code I want to be executed post deployment.

```
resource deploymentscript 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommands@2022-08-01' = {
  parent: virtualMachine
  name: 'postDeploymentPSInstall'
  location: location
  properties: {
    source: {
      script: '''sudo apt-get update &&\
      sudo apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https software-properties-common &&\
      wget -q "https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/packages-microsoft-prod.deb" &&\
      sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb &&\
      sudo apt-get update &&\
      sudo apt-get install -y powershell &&\
      pwsh'''
    }
  }
}
```

I searched for solutions on the web but only found conflicting explanations. I made the code above with the help of this [tutorial](https://www.errush.org/blogposts/deploymentscripts-in-bicep/). The only difference I see is that I'm using Bash and not PowerShell like the blog post author. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did the script fail or not executed ? what was the deployment status regarding the runCommand ?

Comment: The script did execute. The VM was deployed. The code you see above just seems to have been ignored.

Comment: I was able to deploy linux VM from local to Azure and run bash script using run command from the portal. If that works for you, I can provide you the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> To deploy an Ubuntu VM on Azure and **automatically** execute a few lines of Bash code right after the VM is deployed:

I tried to create a `Linux` VM and used `run` command to install PowerShell inside the VM while deployment and was able to achieve the desired results by running below `bicep` file.

```
@description('Name of the Network Security Group')
param networkSecurityGroupName string = 'SecGroupNet'
var publicIPAddressName = '${vmName}PublicIP'
var networkInterfaceName = '${vmName}NetInt'
var osDiskType = 'Standard_LRS'
var subnetAddressPrefix = '10.1.0.0/24'
var addressPrefix = '10.1.0.0/16'

var linuxConfiguration = {
  disablePasswordAuthentication: true
  ssh: {
    publicKeys: [
      {
        path: '/home/${adminUsername}/.ssh/authorized_keys'
        keyData: adminPassword
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource nic 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2021-05-01' = {
  name: networkInterfaceName
  location: location
  properties: {
    ipConfigurations: [
      {
        name: 'ipconfig1'
        properties: {
          subnet: {
            id: subnet.id
          }
          privateIPAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'
          publicIPAddress: {
            id: publicIP.id
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    networkSecurityGroup: {
      id: nsg.id
    }
  }
}

resource nsg 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2021-05-01' = {
  name: networkSecurityGroupName
  location: location
  properties: {
    securityRules: [
      {
        name: 'SSH'
        properties: {
          priority: 1000
          protocol: 'Tcp'
          access: 'Allow'
          direction: 'Inbound'
          sourceAddressPrefix: '*'
          sourcePortRange: '*'
          destinationAddressPrefix: '*'
          destinationPortRange: '22'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-05-01' = {
  name: virtualNetworkName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        addressPrefix
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-05-01' = {
  parent: vnet
  name: subnetName
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: subnetAddressPrefix
    privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
    privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
  }
}

resource publicIP 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses@2021-05-01' = {
  name: publicIPAddressName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Basic'
  }
  properties: {
    publicIPAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'
    publicIPAddressVersion: 'IPv4'
    dnsSettings: {
      domainNameLabel: dnsLabelPrefix
    }
    idleTimeoutInMinutes: 4
  }
}

resource vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2021-11-01' = {
  name: vmName
  location: location
  properties: {
    hardwareProfile: {
      vmSize: vmSize
    }
    storageProfile: {
      osDisk: {
        createOption: 'FromImage'
        managedDisk: {
          storageAccountType: osDiskType
        }
      }
      imageReference: {
        publisher: 'Canonical'
        offer: 'UbuntuServer'
        sku: ubuntuOSVersion
        version: 'latest'
      }
    }
    networkProfile: {
      networkInterfaces: [
        {
          id: nic.id
        }
      ]
    }
    osProfile: {
      computerName: vmName
      adminUsername: adminUsername
      adminPassword: adminPassword
      linuxConfiguration: ((authenticationType == 'password') ? null : linuxConfiguration)
    }
  }
}

resource deploymentscript 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommands@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: vm
  name: 'linuxscript'
  location: location
  properties: {
    source: {
      script: '''
                # Update the list of packages
                sudo apt-get update;
                #Install pre-requisite packages.
                sudo apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https software-properties-common;
                #Download the Microsoft repository GPG keys
                wget -q "https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/packages-microsoft-prod.deb";
                #Register the Microsoft repository GPG keys
                sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb;
                #Update the list of packages after we added packages.microsoft.com
                sudo apt-get update;
                #Install PowerShell
                sudo apt-get install -y powershell;
                #Start PowerShell
                pwsh
              '''
    }
  }
}

output adminUsername string = adminUsername
output hostname string = publicIP.properties.dnsSettings.fqdn
output sshCommand string = 'ssh $ {adminUsername}@${publicIP.properties.dnsSettings.fqdn}'
```

*Deployed Successfully*:

[image]

[image]

*From Azure Portal:*

[image]

*After the deployment, When I* `ssh’d` *into my VM and ran* `Pwsh` *to check if PowerShell was installed*

***Installed successfully:***

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-bicep?tabs=CLI), [run command template-MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/runcommands?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is misunderstanding what the **&&** does.

The shell will attempt to run **semi-simultaneously** all parts, some possibly clobbering others or not having necessary preconditions in place before starting!

**Replace** all instances of "**&&\**" with "**;\**" and your script should work, meaning the commands will run sequentially, waiting for the previous line to complete before attempting the subsequent lines.

Comment: `&&` _does_ run commands synchronously and sequentially, albeit _conditionally_. That is, the RHS is only run if the LHS indicated success via exit code `0`. The use of `&&` in the initial post is most likely deliberate, using a common idiom in POSIX-compatible shells that chains commands in a manner that avoids unnecessary invocation of subsequent commands if a previous command in the chain unexpectedly failed.