# Azure (Bicep) - deploymentScripts - Reference file path

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-bicep

I currently have a deployment script that I am calling in an Azure Bicep file.

```
resource powershellImportCertKeyVault 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'powershellImportCertKeyVault'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzurePowerShell'
  properties: {
    forceUpdateTag: utcValue
    azPowerShellVersion: '8.3'
    scriptContent: '''
      $rootDir = $PSScriptRoot
      $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "not-real-password" -AsPlainText -Force
      Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "testing-keyvault-001" -Name "ExampleCertificate2" -FilePath "./test-cert.pfx" -Password $Password
    '''
    arguments: '-name ${testPSName}'
    timeout: 'PT1H'
    cleanupPreference: 'OnSuccess'
    retentionInterval: 'P1D'
  }
```

This script is attempting to call the Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate az powershell command to import a .pfx certificate into KeyVault.
The problem I am having is that I can't seem to reference the .pfx file (Which is sitting in the same folder as my bicep module) in this deployment script!
Whenever I run this, I get the error:

```
[31;1mCan not find file './test-cert.pfx'.
```

Does anyone know how I can reference files in this deployment script?

Comment: That's because `deploymentscript` resources don't run on your PC, they run in Azure Container Instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I tried the same script in my environment and the deployment succeeded with no "file reference not found" issues.*

```
@description('Specifies the location for resources.')
param  location  string = 'eastUS'
resource  powershellImportCertKeyVault  'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
name: 'powershellImportCertKeyVault'
location: location
kind: 'AzurePowerShell'
properties: {
forceUpdateTag: ''
azPowerShellVersion: '8.3'
scriptContent: '''
$rootDir = $PSScriptRoot
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "jahnavikeyvaults" -Name "jahnavikeyvaults-jahnavicert-20221202.pem" -FilePath "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Downloads\jahnavikeyvaults-jahnavicert-20221202.pem" -Password $Password
'''
arguments: '-name $test'
timeout: 'PT1H'
cleanupPreference: 'OnSuccess'
retentionInterval: 'P1D'
}
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

You can execute deployment scripts locally and then deploy them to Azure. Refer here to develop and run [deployment scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74478948/post-deployment-bash-script-in-bicep-file-does-not-execute/74531629#74531629) to install `PowerShell`once VM is created.

***Imported certificate successfully:***

[image]

**Note:** To avoid conflicts, make sure the certificate is in `.pem/pfx` format while importing or downloading it.